# display image using byteArray failed (Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2124:Loaded file is an unknown type)

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, image-processing, arrays

Problem:can't display jpeg image when using the byteArray as `source`.

suppose there is an existing image named "card".`<Image id="card"/>`.
Here is the scenario:

1.get bitmapData: `var bitmapData:BitmapData = Bitmap(card.content).bitmapData`

2.get byteArray: `var pixels:ByteArray = bitmapData.getPixels(bitmapData.rect)`

3.attach the byteArray to an new Image: `var another:Image = new Image(); another.source = pixels.`

(I also tried to use another way, still can't work: `var loader:Loader = new Loader(); loader.loader(pixels);`)
**loader.loader(pixels) will throw an error!** **The error is "Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2124":Loaded file is an unknown type**

Answer (score 1):

Refer below links...

http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Loading_a_local_file_to_a_byte_array_in_Flash_Play-16715.html

http://blog.yoz.sk/2009/10/bitmap-bitmapdata-bytearray/